# kNN k-fold CV Error Rate

Tags: r, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have run 10-fold Cross-Validation on kNN to predict my optimal size of k (neighbors). I'm pretty sure I've calculated my model correctly, following to a tee this process: http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/crossvalidation.html.

Yet, the misclassification rate increases almost in a linear fashion, as k increases (I've attached the plot I ran). Is this normal? I haven't seen this before today. Is this something that happens every so often, merely due to the data set?[image]

The code I used:

```
#create folds
folds<-createFolds(clData,k=10)

ks <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)
res <- sapply(ks, function(k) {
  ##try out each version of k
  res.k <- sapply(seq_along(folds), function(i) {
    ##loop over each of the 10 cross-validation folds
    ##predict the held-out samples using k nearest neighbors
    pred <- knn(train=X[ -folds[[i]],1:300 ],
                test=X[ folds[[i]],1:300 ],
                cl=X[ -folds[[i]],301 ], k = k)
    ##the ratio of misclassified samples
    mean(X4[ folds[[i]], 301] != pred)
  })
  ##average over the 10 folds
  mean(res.k)
})

plot(ks, res, type="o",ylab="misclassification error")
```

Note: I did not include the data set due to confidentiality.